# Maven EAR plugin, rename the app

Tags: java, maven, ear

I have a maven ear module.

For example, its artifact ID is `MyApp`. Maven creates ear archive whith name `MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear`, Glassfish admin panel show deployed app with name `MyApp`

I want to change default name. I tried this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <displayName>mySuperName</displayName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But it changes only one string inside the application.xml:

`<display-name>mySuperName</display-name>`

Does I have any other options to rename the app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the [`finalName`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html#finalName) element:

```
<configuration>
    <finalName>myFinalName</finalName>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How can I forece maven-deploy-plugin to use this file to deploy it to artefact reposiotry and not use the default ear-name?