# How te rename EAR artifact with Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-ear-plugin

I have a project Maven ear modules, and i like to rename the ear from  ProjectIt-4.1.0.ear to ProjectIt-4_1_0.ear in fact to have a version like that : x_y_z to resolve a deployement contraints

Comment: Did you already tried something ? Something like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173316/maven-ear-plugin-rename-the-app

Comment: Yes, but i need to rename juste version from x.y.z to x_y_z

Comment: And you want this to be automaticaly done ... I see

Comment: yes automatically to deliver thé artifact to à deployment mechanism

Comment: I believe the version can only contain numbers and dots: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724415/maven-artifact-and-groupid-naming

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom property holding your key with your own separtor between major, minor and maintenance version.
Then you can use that property in the build name of your artifact:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <custom.version>x_y_z</custom.version>
  </properties>
  ...
  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${custom.version}</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Meanwhile, I wouldn't advice such a method of shipping artifacts version, because it would not fit the common version syntax. You can read more about Semantic Versionin in [semver](http://semver.org/).

Comment: Thank's for answer, but in this case i must update the version in every version increment :(

Comment: Sure, that is why it would be better if you stick to the default schema. The release plugin won't be able to do the incrementation for you.