# Intellij 2018.1.6 deploy glassfish application name contains .ear extension

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, glassfish, ear, payara

Created a Run/Debug configuration to deploy to a payara glassfish server.

It is deploying the built .ear file `MyApp.ear` built with maven to the server but when you look at the application in the Admin console the name is `MyApp.ear`.

What am I missing that would deploy it with the application name of just `MyApp`?

If I deploy the MyApp.ear file using the admin console the application name defaults to `MyApp`, so what do I need to do so Intellij does the same?

Update 7-23-2018:

I already had finalName here in my ear pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <finalName>MyApp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.example.myapp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>war-module</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/MyApp</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>com.example.myapp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ejb-module</artifactId>
                    </ejbModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So I tried moving it to with in configuration with same results:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>MyApp</finalName>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.example.myapp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>war-module</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/MyApp</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>com.example.myapp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ejb-module</artifactId>
                    </ejbModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is something specific to Intellij when it deploys it, it's like it doesn't use these values and just uses the file name for the application name.

Comment: Try using `finalName` in configuration https://stackoverflow.com/a/18173399/2000323.

Comment: Even tried application-name still not working.